# Ionic 2 Form Validation

Tags: validation, ionic-framework, ionic2, forms

I have two forms on a page, there is a billing form and a shipping form. The user can decide whether the billing form is the same as the shipping form by toggling a toggle button. I want to force the user to enter all the details before the submit button. But when the user decides that billing address is the same as shipping, he will just have to enter the shipping details.

I have added `required` to all the fields, but I am able to submit the form without entering the details.

```
enter <ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="header"> 
<button ion-button menuToggle>
  <ion-icon name="menu">
  </ion-icon>
</button>
<ion-title text-center><img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" 
(click)="goHome()">
</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content text-wrap class="billing-address-form">
    <div class="page-name">
        <ion-item no-lines padding-left>
    <b color="side-heading-color" text-uppercase>{{"Checkout"| translate}}
          </b>
  </ion-item>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngIf="!values.isLoggedIn" class="side-heading-background Returningcustomer" no-lines>
  <ion-label color="side-heading-color">{{"Returningcustomer?Loginhere.." | translate}}
    <ion-icon ios="ios-log-in" md="md-log-in">
    </ion-icon>
  </ion-label>
  <ion-toggle checked="" [(ngModel)]="islogin" name="logIn">
  </ion-toggle>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngIf="islogin && !values.isLoggedIn" class="login-form">
  <form #f="ngForm">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>{{"username" | translate}}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input required type="email" [(ngModel)]="loginData.username" name="email">
        </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>{{"password" | translate}}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input required type="password" [(ngModel)]="loginData.password" name="password">
        </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list> 
    <div class="login-button"><!-- [disabled]="buttonSubmitLogin" -->
      <button ion-button block color="button-color" type="submit" text-uppercase (click)="doLogin(loginData)">{{buttonText2}}
      </button> 
    </div>
  </form>
      </div>

      <ion-item-group padding>
  <ion-item-divider color="light">Delivery Address</ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'FirstName' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress.first_name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'LastName' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress.last_name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="email" placeholder="{{ 'Email' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress.email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="phone" placeholder="{{ 'Phone' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress.phone"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{'StreetAddress' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress.address_1"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{'Landmark' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress.address_2"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'City' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress.city"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'Country' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress.country" disabled="true"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
      </ion-item-group>
      <ion-item-divider color="light">
  <ion-label>Billing Address(Same as Delivery)</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle color="dark" [(ngModel)]="sameAddress" item-right></ion-toggle>
      </ion-item-divider>
     <ion-item-group *ngIf="!sameAddress">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'FirstName' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="billingAddress.first_name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'LastName' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="billingAddress.last_name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="email" placeholder="{{ 'Email' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="billingAddress.email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="phone" placeholder="{{ 'Phone' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="billingAddress.phone"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{'StreetAddress' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="billingAddress.address_1"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'Landmark' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="billingAddress.address_2"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'City' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="billingAddress.city"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'Country' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="billingAddress.country" disabled="true"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
      </ion-item-group>
      <ion-item-group radio-group>
  <ion-item-divider>{{ 'Delivery Method' | translate }}</ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label padding-left>{{shipmethod.title}} ( $ {{shipmethod.cost | number:'1.2-2'}})</ion-label>
    <ion-radio checked="true" value="shipmethod.id"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
      </ion-item-group>
    </ion-list>



      <ion-list>
  <ion-item class="side-heading-background order-review-header" no-lines>
    <ion-label color="side-heading-color">{{"Yourorder" | translate}}
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <!-- *ngFor="let item of values.cart; let i = index" -->
  <div *ngFor="let item of cart; let i = index">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-75>
        <ion-label no-margin [innerHTML]="item.name + ' - (' + item.quantity +')'">
        </ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-25 text-right><!-- currency:values.currency:true -->
        <ion-label no-margin>GH¢ {{1*item.price | number:'1.2-2'}}
        </ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-75>
      <ion-label no-margin>{{"SubTotal" | translate}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-25 text-right>
      <ion-label no-margin>GH¢ {{ 1*values.subTotal | number:'1.2-2' }}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-75>
      <ion-label no-margin>
        <b>{{"Totals" | translate}}
        </b>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-25 text-right>
      <ion-label no-margin>
        <b>GH¢ {{1*values.total | number:'1.2-2'}}
        </b>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-item class="side-heading-background payment-method-header" no-lines>
  <ion-label color="side-heading-color">{{"SelectPaymentMethod" | translate}}
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
<div *ngIf="form.payment">
  <ion-list no-margin text-wrap radio-group [(ngModel)]="payment_method" (ngModelChange)="changePayment()">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let method of form.payment | keys">
      <ion-label class="payment-method-title">{{method.value.title}}
      </ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="{{method.value.id}}">
      </ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="side-heading-background">
    <ion-label class="payment-instructions" [innerHTML]="form.payment_instructions">
    </ion-label> 
  <ion-item no-lines class="side-heading-background">
  <ion-label>{{"I Agree" | translate}} <a (click)="terms()">{{"Terms and Conditions" | translate}}</a>
  </ion-label>
  <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="termsAgreed" name="terms">
  </ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
  <div class="button-margin">
    <button ion-button color="button-color" text-uppercase [disabled]="values.total < 1" block secondary type="submit" class="button button-block button-default" (click)="payViaSite()">{{"PlaceOrder" | translate}}
    </button> 
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you can do is disabling the submit button

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
```

Or do function only when form is valid

template

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.valid)">
  ...
    //code with submit button
  ...
</form>
```

component

```
onSubmit(valid : boolean)
{
 if(valid == true)
   {
   //do action
   }
}
```